# Tesseract failing on openCV Mat (installation issue?)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, tesseract

I thought about putting this on superuser or something, but since my problem has to do with what is happening after compilation, I think here is best.

My system: `ubuntu 14.04` `g++ 4.9`

I am attempting to use tesseract in my C++ program.

So, after quite the struggle, I got tesseract to install with no errors during installation. My problem is that, after compiling and running my program, I get the seemingly rare error of:

```
index >= 0 && index < size_used_:Error:Assert failed:in file ../ccutil/genericvector.h, line 512
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What little I could find out about this error is that it can sometimes be caused by missing language data, but I see all of the proper files in the proper folders, according to [this](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe).

Software versions: `tesseract 3.02.02`, `leptonica-1.71`, `libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8`

My source for the tesseract installation: [here](https://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02.tar.gz). I started by trying tesseract 3.03 but it would fail during `make`.

I compiled using these flags with no warnings:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 alt_2.cpp -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --cflags tesseract` -o alt_2 `pkg-config --libs opencv` `pkg-config --libs tesseract`
```

And here is my code that uses tesseract:

```
#include "tesseract/baseapi.h"
...
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
tess.Init(NULL, lang, tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK);
tess.SetImage((uchar*)col0.data, col0.cols, col0.rows, 1, col0.cols);

tess.GetUTF8Text();
```

`tess.GetUTF8Text();` is what causes the error. if it is commented out, the error doesn't occur. `col0` is my Mat image.

I am all out of ideas and patience with this for the moment. So if any kind soul has experience with this, please help.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions, but I got it working.

So, I deleted everything and did a fresh install of tesseract 3.0.3. While making the file I still got the error

```
libtool: link: g++ -std=c++11 -o .libs/tesseract tesseract-
tesseractmain.o  ./.libs/libtesseract.so -lrt -llept -lpthread
./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to some_leptonic_functions
```

So what the issue was is that although `tesseract -v` reported `leptonica-1.71`, there was also a debian package of it that had been installed by `apt-get` that was older. So after doing `sudo apt-get remove libleptonica-dev` the make completed free of errors and I was able to run the code perfectly.

To be clear, this required installing libleptonica and tesseract by source, NOT `apt-get`.

I hope that this helps someone, because this was a frustrating process.

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question. Far better that than keep the knowledge to yourself.